# Tag: mathematica-core

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently a tag was created:  [mathematica-core](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica-core)

Does this serve any purpose?   Should it be set as a synonym for another tag?  Which one?

Comment: At the moment there are no questions with this tag.  I removed the tag from a question because it seemed unnecessary, but unfortunately I cannot find the question now.  Do you think we need to keep the tag at all at this moment?  If not, let's just let it drop out of the system (I believe it'll expire after some time)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that `mathematica-` is redundant, whatever the purpose of this tag.

It should be replaced with [kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel) or [core-language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-language) as appropriate.